# Cyrus-Imapd, доставка в определенную imap папку

Tags: email, linux, sendmail

Я хочу, чтобы заработала *plus-addressing* в *imapd*: чтобы при отправке на адрес `username+subfolder@domain.tld` письмо легло в `subfolder`, а не в `INBOX`.

Вводная информация:

1. отправляю на ящик `username+subfolder@...`
2. права для *anyone* на *user.username* и *user.username.subfolder* равны *lrsp* (делал и просто *p*, но для надежности уже пустился во все тяжкие)

В тестах - доставка в папки работает. Протестировал:

```
$ cat /tmp/msg.txt | /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -m subfolder username@domain.tld
```

все ок, но в реальности все письма летят в корень.

куда еще глядеть?

Answer (score 1):

обнаружил ошибку:

> emailaccount+sharedfolder.subfolder.subfolder@domain.ru